# Calling Codeigniter controller method asynchronously

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, asynchronous

**I have this scenario:**

```
    ----------    1.Call  /register              ---------  3. Async call to
   |  My PC   |  -------------------------->    |My       | ------  
   |          |   2. Server returns view        |Server   |        '  /welcome
    ----------   <--------------------------    |         |       ' 
        |         4. returns welcome message    |         |      ' 
       ---       <--------------------------    |         |     '
                     getting it from 3          |         |   '
                                                 ---------  <'
```

**1.** I call  my register method within the User controller

**2.** Server processes registration data and render view
     by $this->load->view('template_path');
     But I dont want it to finished up right there!
     I want another method within the User controller
     be called----**(3)**

**3.** Server asynchronously calls  user/welcome
     which returns some welcome template view

**4.** The view that comes from 3 will be shown on a modal which
     is hidden within the rendered page from response 2
     and be shown when modal contents are available from this(2nd) response

**How can I do it? Any ideas?**

Comment: Can you call the second user method before rendering the view? You can do multiple method calls from one Async request or you can do an initial call and make the second call when you land on the template_path page. I may be a bit confused on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: As for my understanding you want to call the welcome method after loading the first method's view. Then it is an AJAX call inside the view code to the second method. If you need to call second method also before loading first view then can be a method call insider first method. In that case there is no async.

Comment: @Nish I need to call the second url anyway(SEOpurpose). Say, Registration successfully redirects to profile view then if I put an onload ajax call within the profile page it will work but what if an user lands on the profile page by clicking a link from somewhere else..say from nav bar. So it's not gonna work for me. I have to make sure the welcome method is only called right after a user registers. That's why I need an Async call within the PHP script itself...Not from javascript.

Comment: You can set a flash session when user register and in profile view if the flash variable exists then output Javascript which will do the AJAX call.

Comment: @Nish I've solved it. Thanx for your contribution again. Yeap..it's almost the way you said but with session instead of flash. I wanted to do it the approach I sketched on the question. I wonder no one said anything about that. I think this's how a programmer follows a lame way rather than a great way...and learning of his stumbles atrociously.. Thank you Nish.

Comment: can you post the answer, coz I`m in the same trouble and not expert on this :)

Comment: @BRjava It's easy (but lame way !) . I gotta go somewhere now otherwise I would posted the code for u. You can use <?php if($firsttimelogged): ?>  //Codes to pop up the welcome message from wherever the page redirects to <?php endif ?> . For pop up use jquery $(document).ready(function(){}) ; syntax so that you can even make a post request to show whatever u want to show.